# MySql & Node.js - Update multiple rows & columns

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm using node.js and Mysql, and I would like to update my DB rows and columns per id.
I created the following function, but I continuously keep getting errors:

```
module.exports.editNetworks= async (editedNetworks)=>{
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    var networksToEdit=[];
    var networkObj={};
    for(let network of editedNetworks)
    {
            networkObj={
                id:network.id,
                product_Id:network.product_Id,
                domain_Name:network.domain_Name,
                publisher_Id:network.publisher_Id,
                relationship:network.relationship,
                certification_Id:network.certification_Id,
                lastUpdate:network.lastUpdate, //Needs to convert it to global time zone for every time zone.
            }
            networksToEdit.push(networkObj);
    }
    let netWorkQuery='';
    for(let i in editedNetworks)
    {
        netWorkQuery+=`UPDATE networks SET `
        netWorkQuery+=`domain_Name='${editedNetworks[i].domain_Name}', `
        netWorkQuery+=`publisher_Id='${editedNetworks[i].publisher_Id}', `
        netWorkQuery+=`relationship='${editedNetworks[i].relationship}', `
        netWorkQuery+=`certification_Id='${editedNetworks[i].certification_Id}', `
        netWorkQuery+=`lastUpdate='${editedNetworks[i].lastUpdate}' `
        netWorkQuery+=`WHERE id=${editedNetworks[i].id}; `
    }
    console.log('-------------------------------',netWorkQuery)
    con.query(netWorkQuery, function(err,result,fields){
        if (err)
        {
            console.log('there is an error: ',err);
            throw err;  
        }
        resolve(result);
    })
})
}
```

[image]

Can you please advise what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks :)

Comment: The date value should be surrounded with single quotes. You should use prepared statements to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering, but I still get errors if I update multiple rows.
The single quotes are working, but just if I update one row.

Answer (score 0):

The lastupdate value should be surrounded by single qoutes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering, but I still get errors if I update multiple rows.
The single quotes are working, but just if I update one row.

Comment: Did you enabled muliplestatements in your connection?    

var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});